# Python: Understanding indexing in the use of enumerate with readline

Tags: python, readline, enumerate

Python code:

```
myfile = open("test-file.csv", "r")
for k, line in enumerate(myfile,0):
   if k == 0:
      myline = myfile.readline()
      print(myline)
      break
myfile.close()
```

and test-file.csv is:

```
0. Zeroth
1. First
2. Second
3. Third
```

The output is

```
1. First
```

Why don't I get

```
0. Zeroth
```

?

Comment: Because `for k, line in enumerate` reads a line, and then `myline = myfile.readline()` reads another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you call `myfile.readline()` you have already consumed the zeroth line. (It is stored in the variable `line`, and the variable `k` holds its index 0, which is the condition you are checking).

Then, you read another line (the "first" line) from `myfile`. Try printing `line` instead of `myline`.

Answer (score 1):

Because "zeroth" has already been read in the loop,

```
 myfile = open("test-file.csv", "r")
 for k, line in enumerate(myfile,0):
   if k == 0:
      print(line) # this should output "zeroth"
      myline = myfile.readline() #this will read "First"
      print(myline)
      break
myfile.close()
```